# Finding the stationary points of the curve.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the coordinates of the stationary points on the curve $y=3 xe^{2-x^2}$.

I went ahead and used the product rule to get my derivative, which would later give me the $x$-coordinates. My derivative is:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -6 x^2 (e^{2-x^2}) + 3e^{2-x^2}.$$

My problem is: when I set it equal to $0$, I don't know how to get a straight forward quadratic which would then allow me to get the $x$-coordinates.

Both parts have the $e^{2-x^2}$ in them, but I don't know how separating these terms would help me in any way.

Comment: The  first term in the derivative is not right.

Comment: Sorry, a typo! It should've been x^2!

Comment: Why separate ? You have on the contrary to factor it : $y'=e^{(2-x^2)}(-6x^2+3)$ which is $0$ for $x=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So the derivative is $e^{2-x^2}(3-6x^2)$. Now can you finish?

Comment: would X therefore equal to +- sqrt2 and +- sqrt2/2?

Comment: We have  $x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or if you prefer $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is factor out the $e^{2-x^2}$ like so:

$-3e^{2-x^2}(2x^2-1) = 0$
Now you know that $e^{2-x^2}$ is not 0 for any $x$. So you know $2x^2-1=0$, and you can probably take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}3xe^{2-x^2}=3e^{2-x^2}-6x^2e^{2-x^2}=-3(2x^2-1)e^{2-x^2}$$
This expression equals zero when $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried to overcomplicate it with the use of logarithm to get right of e.

Comment: It is more than unusual to consider points at infinity...

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry about the points at infinity, I wasn't sure whether to include them or not.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok, my bad. Should I edit it out?

Comment: I my opinion, yes. If Matthew gives this as a possible answer to his homework, his instructor will not agree at all...

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to recall that $\mathrm{e}^x$ is never zero for $x \in \Bbb{R}$, so you may divide through and eliminate it.  Alternatively, we can factor it ourt and use the same observation to simplify the factorization.

Since you have the correct derivative, factor the exponential out  $$  \mathrm{e}^{2-x^2}\left( 3-6x^2 \right) = 0  $$
Now we know one or both of the two factors is zero and it can't be the first one, so we must have $3-6x^2 = 0$, or $x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$.